How to deal with academic loneliness?
I am 4 months into a PhD program and in general I am very passionate about research and feel like it’s my destiny. However, the research group I got into is not what I expected. In my master degree (3 year program), I worked closely with PhD students and one postdoc, I have seen their passion and we always had discussions about different papers and recent advances in our field. Now the only person that I can discuss anything is my advisor, but obviously he is quite busy. Senior PhD students are either very busy in the lab or not in the office (they never stay in the office). My year PhD students or master students show absolutely no interest in research, especially PhD students. That is very surprising to me, I am really confused. One might say it's not a big deal as long as you are passionate yourself, but I feel like sharing your experience with others is key in research.
Has anyone had the same experience? Or maybe it’s something normal?

Do you mean specifically "academic loneliness" (no one to interact with in field) or general loneliness (feeling of isolation in life)?

Actually both, i am a new student in this school and I only attend my lab and some classes. All the people I interact with are from my lab. And because nobody shares my interests or don’t have time for this, the only friend I have is my supervisor.

What specific domain are you in? I know since very collaborative domains but also some outright cutthroat ones. What’s "normal" is impossible to say in general.

It it correct to say your fellow students aren’t sociable in the way you were expecting them to be? And have you worked through the details of your advisor’s possible misconduct?

I am a chemistry major, doing research highly related to materials and biochemistry.

I wouldn’t say they are not sociable. They just don’t show general interest in research, for example because I am quite familiar with one guy’s research direction (also freshman as me), I used to send him some publications about his topic from top journals. (Our school doesn’t have a subscription to ALL journals, but I found a way to access all of them) and he literally told me that those papers are useless because their research level is too high, so he needs lower level publications. I was puzzled by this. In other aspects of life, he is very sociable.

To be clear, are you four months or three years into your PhD program? https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/209200/my-phd-supervisor-is-doing-nothing-and-is-probably-involved-in-academic-miscondu

Previous question was asked by another student when I was a master degree student. He is a good friend of mine that was working in our lab during my master degree. His English is not very good, so I asked a question for him (of course he agreed for this before)

@nArA, I just want to say that what you are feeling is valid. The need for community and bonding is central to the human condition. Even if you end up going the way of the (unfortunately) accepted answer, I would encourage you to also seek out other avenues for human interaction. Maybe you can start a small reading group with students from other labs or even departments with broadly related interests. As a CS PhD, I took several classes in Mathematics, and found that I had more in common with the Math folk! It is my hope that you are able to find your community too.

" One might say it's not a big deal as long as you are passionate yourself" <- It is actually very important to have colleagues to chat with and bounce ideas off of; without those, many things are harder, especially collaborations and establishing a network of contacts.

I'll offer a few suggestions for each issue separately though there can be a bit of overlap between the two. They might work, or not, but they will take some effort.
One problem is that doctoral research is so narrow and so focused that what you see is fairly natural, so solutions need to break out of that.
For the "academic loneliness", it might be possible, with the permission and even the help of your advisor, to form a study group that periodically (weekly) discusses issues brought up by members on where they are stuck. In a single lab people might be working toward common goals, or toward tightly focused sub-goals. But people should be generally knowledgeable about the focus of the lab and the wider field.
A less formal solution is to have a daily "designated coffee hour" in which people gather and chat about whatever they need to talk about, whether academics or not. This can include both students and faculty. My experience in grad school was that lots of things got cleared up in the department coffee room. It had a black (actually green) board for helping with laying out problems, with a long table in front of it, along with several couches and chairs.
You can also, possibly, have a designated time and place for lunch periodically where various discussions can be held.
It is a bit early (4 months) for this next suggestion, but long term you want to develop a circle of collaborators. One way to do that is with conference attendance, whether you are presenting or not. That takes time and financial support of course, but when you do make contacts, try to keep them alive, both within and outside your own institution.
Some of the above helps a bit for the academic side. But more can be done on the general life front as well.
You say that people don't share your interests. If you mean generally, not the research topic, then one option is to widen your own interests.
At one place I attended there was a continuous Bridge game (a card game) in a large multiple student office. People would leave it for class or whatever and others would take their place, but it was essentially continuous.
I was part of a group of cycling enthusiasts, both students and (mostly) faculty who would take frequent bike rides (25 miles and up). That break for aerobic exercise was good for both mind and body, though not a lot of conversation during a ride.
One place had a weekly Saturday softball game for (mostly) students and faculty along with spouses. It used up a few hours every week, but again, aerobic breaks are a good thing. Other such things are possible for small groups. Most universities have a gym open to students. Even walking can be used to refresh the mind, and it can be done with one or a few others.
But, look around to see what others might be doing and offer to join in. Spending every waking moment with your head deep in research is sub-optimal for most people.
Going a bit farther afield, if you are a person of faith, many places of worship in university towns have student focused groups. Some congregations are actually mostly students and have many social opportunities. Some of these are especially valuable to students  with families.

One other issue you raise is the lack of interest in research in others. I don't know where you are studying, but in the US this would be natural for beginning grad students who need to get advanced coursework an likely comprehensive exams out of the way before they start on research. Most will have started with only a bachelors and little research experience. If you are in such a system then starting with a masters might make you a bit atypical.

"doctoral research is so narrow and so focused that what you see is fairly natural" <- Disagree. Most doctoral research is not that narrow that there is nothing to talk about with your teammates; and remember, it's not talk about the specifics of OP's own proof of some complex theorem - it's even more general talk about their field that's missing.

@einpoklum, field dependent, perhaps. My doctoral institution had more than 50 professors and more than 100 doctoral students. The only one who was knowledgeable enough to discuss my research with was my advisor. Even a highly regarded other faculty member on my committee admitted that they didn't completely follow my arguments and took my advisor's word for it. He was a superstar so that wasn't a hard decision. A very deep dive into a very narrow well. There were about six others in the world who had the knowledge necessary and most were in Japan.

But could you not discuss the subfield in which your advisor (and you) were active, with other Ph. D. candidates in your department? Or the field in general?

@einpoklum, your comment (and and disagreement with mine) were about the research being narrow, not the overall field. I wouldn't have been much use discussing the research of the other hundred students, with one possible exception (same advisor).

Research group dynamics are always just that, dynamic. They can change quickly with outgoing members and incoming ones. Sometimes it will take a while to build the type of professional (and personal) relationships that match what you are looking for. Perhaps you will find them in a different group.
For most of my PhD, I did not build any lasting relationships with my own group members (who as you similarly describe, while being good sociable people, were not into research as much as I was). I made lifelong friendships with other students in my department (and outside of it) though. As long as you focus on your passions, and make efforts to interact with those around you, you will find people who are likeminded, but do not be surprised if they are not directly in your group (or even in your subfield).

Think this could be an issue for two reasons that may be related to your doctoral pursuits.

If there is no sense of collaboration or colleagiality, then this could be a problem with the lab culture. People mostly working independently on projects with minimal interaction could make it hard to foster projects in the future and issues with communication and transparency making it harder to continue projects or co-author.

Technical limitations in entering a new PhD program. If there is no formal training of certain methodologies or techniques, then I believe it could make it harder to advance academically.


Not sure which applies more to you. Of course, my assumption is that this is more for STEM-related field. Nevertheless, the fact that you have a good working relationship with your advisor is a good sign. You may be able to convince them to promote more meetings, journal clubs, and activities that foster collaboration.

Wisdom comes by disillusionment. So congratulations: you're on your way. While you can certainly finds other places/labs that are more interactive - your current experience is actually reflective of the true nature of the field. As someone said, “In Washington, it's dog eat dog. In academia, it's exactly the opposite.” So if you're truly "very passionate about research and feel like it’s my destiny" - stick with it (but don't expect much change). If not completely certain - you may want to look for another field. Good luck.

Heads up that this is very domain dependent. There are some very collaborative and team oriented science domains. What’s indicative of a no-nonsense group in one domain means you have a bunch of backstabbing psychos in another.

I always consider answering the question in the title, not in the text itself. You are answering the question in the text, saying it is normal. But that doesn't mean there is not an answer on how to deal with it.
